# Swing rendering... does it always have to be repaint() and paintComponent()?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

In my program I am using Swing windows for my GUI, and I know that I'm supposed to use repaint and paintComponent methods to render swing components. I also have several custom class objects that need to be rendered inside the main window. For the sake of understanding, my program is a game that will have moving objects that need to be rendered 60 times per second.

In a game development tutorial I watched, the guy used a Jframe with Canvas, but he didn't use the paintComponent method. He simply made his own render() methods to draw all the graphics using graphics context he obtained from creating a bufferStrategy.

So if that works (which it does), why does everyone say to use the paintComponent methods and what exactly is the difference between them?

If I were to use the paintComponent way of doing things, how would I use bufferStrategy with that?

Comment: Yeah I am much more familiar with Swing than AWT. What exactly is Canvas used for?

Comment: You mean from Canvas? So it would be Canavs extends JPanel?

Comment: Ignore me, listen to @MadProgrammer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In a game development tutorial I watched, the guy used a Jframe with Canvas, but he didn't use the paintComponent method. He simply made his own render() methods to draw all the graphics using graphics context he obtained from creating a bufferStrategy.

`Canvas` is an AWT component, using a `BufferStrategy`, you take over the painting process and become responsible for update the `Graphics` context and scheduling it's push to the hardware/screen.

This is commonly known as "active painting", as you are constantly (one would assume at a constant frame rate), updating the buffer.

Swing uses a passive paint process, so you never know when a paint process might occur.  Swing has it's own mechanisms for determining what should be repainted and when.  Using `repaint`, you make a request to these mechanisms that your component be repainted, but there is no guarantee that a paint cycle will be initiated because of it.

If you use any Swing component for you painting, you MUST use `repaint` and `paintComponent`, as the Swing is responsible for providing the context onto which you can paint.

If you want to use `Canvas`, then you can use a `BufferStrategy` instead.

Essentially, they are different approaches to painting.  Remember though, if you use a `BufferStrategy`, you lose ALL of the Swing API, you CAN NOT use Swing components with this approach, as they are not designed to work this way...

Comment: Hmm... is there a good substitute for BufferStrategy that is swing compatible? I really like Swing components, but I need to constantly draw images which might slow down my graphics.

Comment: @zephos2014 No, but unless you have an ABSOLUTE problem which can't be solved in Swing, there's probably little need to worry just yet...

Comment: Are you inferring that a BufferStrategy would not be necessary? I have no idea how swing decides to paint things, so I wouldn't know. The reason I thought it would be best to use a BufferStrategy is because I will have animations. Does swing handle animations well?

Comment: @zephos2014 You have to remember, Swing is a UI framework, built on top of AWT, designed to solve issues with AWT (customisation been one of them).  It was designed for a purpose.  If you can work within that framework to achieve what you want, then good, if you can't then you need to investigate other solutions...Swing provides you some nice components to interact with the user

Comment: also, I found this saying that swing and awt are more compatible now: http://java.dzone.com/news/a-farewell-heavyweightlightwei

Comment: @zephos2014 Have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for deatils about the painting process

Comment: @zephos2014 With regards to mixing heavy and lightweight components - despite what seems to be said, I've never found it to work.  Heavyweight components are generally attached to a single native peer and are painted via this process.  Lightweight components share a single native peer and need to be coordinated when updated, this is done by the RepaintManager